# Al ulitizar Listas en Java ¿cómo puedo obtener el índice al buscar un objeto?

Tags: java, lista

La clase Compañia guarda una lista con instancias de la clase Cliente el cual tiene un rut y otros atributos. Al utilizar el método anyMatch() devuelve true o false si lo encuentra dentro de la lista. Pero ademas necesito saber cuál es su índice dentro de la lista.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Compañia {
    String nombre;
    List<Cliente> clienteCelular = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean buscarCliente(String r){
    return clienteCelular.stream().anyMatch(cli -> cli.rut.equals(r))    
}
```

esta es la Clase Cliente

```
public class Cliente {
    String rut, nombre,sexo;
    Celular celular;
    int edad;
    boolean plan;
```

Agradezco cualquier aporte

Comment: No estoy al tanto de una función existente que acepte un Predicate y que te devuelva el índice. Tendrías que hacerlo manualmente con un bucle. Pero, ¿realmente necesitas que te devuelva un índice? ¿Por qué no devolver de una vez la instancia de cliente si lo encuentra y null si no lo encuentra?

Comment: No se en realidad que estas haciendo, pero quizás te sea conveniente emplear un HashMap en lugar del arraylist, o puedes también recorrer el arraylist y comparar uno por uno y apoyarte de un contador el cual te dirá su posición.
Un simple for quizás para comparar y saber la posición.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer con streams pero es peligroso:

```
public int buscarCliente(String r){
        int index  = IntStream.range(0, clienteCelular.size())
            .filter(userInd-> clienteCelular.get(userInd).nombre.equals(r))
            .findFirst().orElse(-1);
        return index;
}
```

El principal problema es el manejo de nulos en caso de que no encuentre el resultado, el null pointer exception no se atrapará y deberás de regresar el valor bandera, en este caso -1 en caso de error encerrando el valor en un trycatch y silenciando la excepción, lo cual no es muy elegante.

```
public int buscarCliente(String r){
    int index  = -1;
    try{
        index=IntStream.range(0, clienteCelular.size())
            .filter(userInd-> clienteCelular.get(userInd).nombre.equals(r))
            .findFirst().getAsInt();
    }catch (NoSuchElementException ignored){
    }
    return index;
}
```

Es más seguro hacerlo a la antiguita ( y posiblemente sea más legible ):

```
public int buscarCliente(String r){
    int index = -1;
    int bound = clienteCelular.size();
    for (int userInd = 0; userInd < bound; userInd++) {
        if (clienteCelular.get(userInd).nombre.equals(r)) {
            index = userInd;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

La explicación es sencilla, debes crear los índices y recorrer el vector por índices filtrando por el campo que quieres obtener, si no existiera entonces debes regresar una bandera como por ejemplo -1 para indicar que no se halló.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [List.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) junto con [Stream.findAny()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--):

```
public int buscarCliente(String r)
{
    Cliente clienteABuscar = clienteCelular.stream()
            .filter(cliente -> cliente.getRut().equals(r))
            .findAny()      // Devuelve Optional<Cliente>
            .orElse(null);  // TODO: decidir qué hacer si no existe

    return clienteCelular.indexOf(clienteABuscar);
}
```

Recuerda que `findAny()` devuelve un [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html?is-external=true), lo que puedes usar para lanzar una excepción, o crear un nuevo cliente en caso de que no lo encuentres en la lista.

También puedes usar [findFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) para buscar el *primer* cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno hice un código medio en el aire, sin embargo creo que la estructura se asemeja un toque a lo que pedis, te enumero un par de cambios que le hice.

1) el nombre de la clase sin ñ, desde el vamos, sólo para que lo tengas en cuenta nomas.

2) El método que vos tenías declarado como boolean, lo cambié  a int, porqué? porque el boolean en este caso lo podemos tomar como una condición adentro de un if, que si se da esa condición nos devuelva el si hubo un match en este caso, nunca usé ése Stream pero efectivamente devuelve un boolean, si da true entra en la condición y el index que tenía valor 0 ahora va a tener un valor asignado por el método indexOf(String str); el cual encuentra la posición del primer objeto que cumpla con las características que nombrás.

3) EL método en sí sólo te devuelve la posición del objeto en cuestión. Sin embargo evalúa la condición que pedís.

4) El Stream que hiciste no lo probé debe andar muy bien, sin embargo para tener un control más claro sobre lo que estás codificando quizás podrías hacer lo mismo a manopla de una forma menos fashion que con stream pero sería mérito tuyo completamente.

5) Acá te dejo el código que hice, para aplicar métodos distintos a los comunes, usé iterator para que veas unas formas distintas de recorrer la List<>, otra cosa, copiá el código que te estoy pasando y fijate su te imprime la posición en la cual está declarado el String.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Compania {

List<Cliente> clienteCelular = new ArrayList<>();
int index;
Cliente cliente;

public int buscarCliente(String r) {

    Cliente c1 = new Cliente();
    c1.nombre = "ejemplo1";
    Cliente c2 = new Cliente();
    c2.nombre = "ejemplo2";
    Cliente c3 = new Cliente();
    c3.nombre = "ejemplo3";
    clienteCelular = Arrays.asList(c1, c2, c3);

    /*
     * Recorremos cada elemento de la List<>
     * 
     */
    for (Cliente item : clienteCelular) {

        /*
         * Mientras la List<> tenga algún objeto en su contenido que realice una
         * condición adentro del bloque
         */
        while (clienteCelular.iterator().hasNext()) {

            /*
             * Si ése objeto es igual en su contenido a 'r' entonces le asignamos el índice
             * a la variable temporal
             */
            if (clienteCelular.stream().anyMatch(cli -> cli.nombre.equals(r))) {
                /*
                 * Acá es donde al objeto que tiene el String igual al que buscas se le asigna a
                 * la variable int temporal que vamos a usar en el resultado
                 */
                index = clienteCelular.indexOf(item);

                /*
                 * Estos String no son necesarios sólo los pongo para que veas que pasa en cada
                 * bloque
                 */
                System.out.println("El " + item.nombre + " se encuentra en la posición: " + index + " de la Lista");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    /* Este es el resultado del índice buscado */
    return index;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Compania c = new Compania();
    System.out.println("El objeto con el String seleccionado de parámetro se encuentra en la posición número: "
            + c.buscarCliente("ejemplo3"));
}

}
```

Como ejemplo agregué tres elementos a la List<> harcodeados, como mala práctica no declaré los atributos como private, sin embargo eso una vez que el código sale andando se hace sobre la marcha. ojalá que te sirva, lo probé en mi entorno funciona bien, sin embargo tiene baches pero para tu objetivo que es encontrar un índice de un objeto que posea un String iría bien, el booleano sigue estando, sólo que embebido dentro del método que al finalizar devuelve un int.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mucho mas reducido y eficiente sin código extra y más limpio te quedaría así:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Compania {

List<Cliente> clienteCelular = new ArrayList<>();
int index;
Cliente cliente;

public int buscarCliente(String r) {

    Cliente c1 = new Cliente();
    c1.nombre = "ejemplo1";
    Cliente c2 = new Cliente();
    c2.nombre = "ejemplo2";
    Cliente c3 = new Cliente();
    c3.nombre = "ejemplo3";
    clienteCelular = Arrays.asList(c1, c2, c3);


        for (Cliente item : clienteCelular) {

            while (clienteCelular.iterator().hasNext()) {

                if (clienteCelular.stream().anyMatch(cli -> cli.nombre.equals(r))) {
                    index = clienteCelular.indexOf(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    return index;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Compania c = new Compania();
    System.out.println("El objeto con el String seleccionado de parámetro se encuentra en la posición número: "+ c.buscarCliente("ejemplo3"));
}

}
```

Usé otra forma diferente de recorrer la List<>, con el método iterator(), sólo para proponer una idea diferente al for clásico.

Axel.

Comment: @pablo fijate si te sirve la respuesta

Comment: gracias por la respuesta tan completa, funciona bien en mi codigo. El codigo de la imagen cambia un poco la estructura e integra una validacion inicial que incluire en el codigo final.

Answer (score 1):

Muy fácil bro, utiliza la función IndexOf del ArrayList

```
    public static int getMasBarato() {
    
    int indice = 0;
    
    float aux = lista_vehiculo.get(0).getPrecio();
    
    for(Vehiculo vehiculo:lista_vehiculo){
        if(vehiculo.getPrecio() < aux){
            indice = lista_vehiculo.indexOf(vehiculo);
        }            
    }
    
    
    return indice;
}
```

Comment: Da un mejor explicación si tutear a quien hace la pregunta, ya que no es necesario y si una mejor explicación.